Search box input is not getting focused on shift tab
In dialog box, there is one input search box and one close button. On tab click both elements are focusable and readable by NVDA but shift+tab not allowing me to focus inside an search box but instead moving to an outer div and then the close button.
It is salseforce project, LWC components are used and there are different components for input searchbar and close button.
I have used tabindex="-1" for dialog box parent div and tabindex="0" for input searchbox and close button.
To trap focus I have used below javascript code in close button component.
handleFocusOut(event) {
   const modal = this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="articleModal"]`);
    var related = event.relatedTarget;
    var dataindexval = related.getAttribute('data-index')

    if (dataindexval == '0') {
       // If focus is leaving, bring it back to the modal
       this.template.querySelector('.searchBox').focus();
        //event.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        if (dataindexval == '1') {
            // If focus is leaving, bring it back to the modal
            this.template.querySelector('.closeWrap').focus();
        } 
    }     
}


From the code it’s unclear so far what event focusout is bound to, and wether inert and aria-hidden are used on the underlying contents.

Aren’t you using lightning-modal? According to its documentation, it takes care of focus management. I’m not sure whether it renders all other content inert, which is important for a modal as well.

Can you post a link to an example page ? Or at least, also provide the actual generated HTML code ? Your script alone isn't sufficient to help.
